# qt hiding a control on showEvent()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I call show() on a window and it has several controls and all controls are displayed.

One of the controls is a custom control that inherits from `QFrame`.

I want to hide this control if a particular flag is set. So, I have

```
void MyCustomControl::showEvent ( QShowEvent * /* evt */ )
{
    if (!m_visibleAllowed)
        hide();
}
```

While this hides the control, it makes the control goofy; it looks frozen. When the window is resized, the area where the control is supposed to be does not get refreshed. Searching around forums, the idea that I get is that hiding the control is not supposed to be done on `showEvent()` is that true? if so then how/where should I try to hide the control. If hiding the control from `showEvent()` is possible, how can I prevent the control getting frozen.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is with calling hide() during your show event (I can't confirm that it's explicitly disallowed, but it doesn't sound like a good idea in general) and calling hide from your show event is where you really need to have this code then you could use a single shot timer:

```
QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT(hide()) );
```

which will simply defer the execution of the `hide()` function until the next round of the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a [QStackedLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstackedlayout.html) or a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstackedwidget.html) that has two widgets in the stack: your control, and a "blank" QWidget.  If you did that, instead of using show() and hide() on your control, you switch what's on top of the stack.

That way you never try to render a hidden widget - if your control isn't visible, you render the blank QWidget instead - and I suspect this will solve your graphics glitches.

Hope this helps!